# The differential equation of the change of the amount of the nutrition inside of the incubator.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications, simulation

The problem statement is as below.

We will handle the incubator with the microbes inside of it.

The microbe increases consuming a nutrition.

The amount of the nutrition is never increased.

$10^3*P(t):=$ The number of the microbes inside of the incubator at time $t$[h].

$f(t):=$ The amount of the nutrition inside of the incubator.

$P(t):=P_0*$exp$(k*t);$

$k:=0.1386;$

$P_0:=$The return value of $P(t)$ as time $t=0$;

$c\Delta t:=$The amount of the nutrition which is consumed at micro time $\Delta t[h]$ by the $50*10^3$ microbes.

Represent the differential equation of the change of the value of $f(t)$ as parameter $t$ changes with using $c$  ,$P(t)$ .

---

Comment: This is the raw text of your homework. Show you have worked on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I look at it -

Number of microbes at time $t = 10^3 P(t)$

$f(t)$ is the amount of the nutrition at time $t$.

$c \Delta t$ is the amount of nutrition consumed in time $\Delta t$ by $50 \times 10^3$ microbes.

So amount of nutrition consumed in $\Delta t$ at time $t = \displaystyle \frac{c \Delta t}{50 \times 10^3} \times 10^3 \times P(t)$

$\Delta f(t) = \displaystyle \frac{c}{50} P(t) \Delta t$

lead to $\displaystyle \frac{df(t)}{dt} = \frac{c}{50} P(t) \, \, $ (in terms of $c, P(t)$)

If you have to find in terms of $P_0$ replace $P(t)$ with its formula in terms of $P_0$ and $t$.